# Parenthesis invisible in math mode, using classicthesis(eulermath) with lmodern

Tags: classicthesis, parenthesis

I propose to have a look at this MnWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[eulermath,nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
    $$ (x+2)(x-5)$$
\end{document}
```

When compiling (pdflatex), the parenthesis do not appear in the pdf.
The problem disappears when commenting either lmodern, either classicthesis, either only eulermath.
What work around would you suggest ?
Thanks!
S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lmodern` package removes many of the settings of the `eulermath` option and you remain in a very unstable state.

Load `eulervm` later than `lmodern`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\begin{document}

Some text for seeing what happens
\[
(x+2)(x-5)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't think that this is a good idea, typographically, though.

Don't use `$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 1):

If you swap the order of the `\usepackage{lmodern}` and `\usepackage[eulermath,nochapters]{classicthesis}` it should work. i.e. your code should become:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[eulermath,nochapters]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
  $$ (x+2)(x-5)$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It should work? Did you test your code?

Comment: Since `classicthesis` sets the default font to Palatino, loading `lmodern` before it has no effect whatsoever.