# Parentheses disappear in Equation mode in ACM class

Tags: math-mode, brackets, acmart, lmodern

The problem is that when using the font package `lmodern` with the ACM class `acmart.cls`, the parentheses tend to disappear in the final output. Without `lmodern`, `acmart.cls` gives an error. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[sigconf, anonymous=true]{acmart}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\title[XYZ]{XYZ}

\maketitle
\begin{equation}
Output = AES_{K}(0),AES_{K}(1),AES_{K}(2),...
\end{equation}
%
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{PRNGbib}
\end{document}
```

I am using a lot of other math packages too. Both parentheses and curly brackets tend to disappear in the final output as shown below:

[image]

I have already tried adjusting the package order as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255602/parenthesis-invisible-in-math-mode-using-classicthesiseulermath-with-lmodern).

Comment: You shouldn't load font packages with `acmart`.

Comment: The `acmart` document class loads the `libertine` text font package and the `newtxmath` math font package (with option `libertine`). You should under no circumstance be loading the `lmodern` font package while using the `acmart` document class. If, for some reason, you simply must use the `lmodern` font package, don't use the `acmart` document class. Incidentally, I get no error or warning message when running your code *without* the instruction `\usepackage{lmodern}`. Which TeX distribution do you employ?

Comment: @Mico: I am using `MiKTeX`. I have enhanced the MWE to include the document title part now and commenting the package `lmodern` gives me this error "`pdftex error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalabale fonts`".

Comment: Something must have gone wrong during the MikTeX installation process on your machine. I tried your code (with and without the `\usepackage{lmodern}` directive) on both a MikteX2.9 and a MacTeX2017 system and am unable to produce any error messages. Sorry.

Comment: @Mico: That's strange. One more thing which popped up recently is that if you comment the title part along with the `lmodern` package, no output pdf output is produced i.e. 0 pages.  Though the compiler doesn't gives an error, the log file do mentions this error "`!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base): Font LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base at 360 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`". So as you already suggested this seems to be a case of some components missing from the underlying `libertine` font package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get warnings in your log file:

```
Missing character: There is no <B9> in font lmsy9!
Missing character: There is no <B9> in font lmsy9!
Missing character: There is no <BA> in font lmsy9!
Missing character: There is no <B9> in font lmsy9!
Missing character: There is no <BA> in font lmsy9!
Missing character: There is no <B9> in font lmsy9!
Missing character: There is no <BA> in font lmsy9!
```

(the actual output may differ in how it displays `<B9>` and `<BA>`).

The problem is that the `acmart` document class loads `newtxmath` with the option `libertine`, which assigns different mathcodes to `(` and `)`, precisely `"42B9` for `)` and `52BA` for `)` and this explains the “missing character” warnings.

The standard mathcodes are, respectively, `"4028` and `"5029`. You *might* get away with such problems by redefining the mathcodes:

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {operators}{"28}{largesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"29}{largesymbols}{"01}
```

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf, anonymous=true]{acmart}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {operators}{"28}{largesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"29}{largesymbols}{"01}

\begin{document}

\title[XYZ]{XYZ}

\maketitle
\begin{equation}
Output = AES_{K}(0),AES_{K}(1),AES_{K}(2),...
\end{equation}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{PRNGbib}

\end{document}
```

Note, however, that it's possible to have other mismatches between the defined mathcodes and those expected by `lmodern`. Also some parts of the document may use Libertine nonetheless.

[image]

Final advice: the `acmart` class has been carefully written to comply with the standards of ACM and affiliate conferences. Changing the appearance of the output by loading different fonts than what's defined in the class should *not* be done and it could be a good reason for rejection of a submission.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Certainly, I will not like to do that but can't help it. Without loading `lmodern` I get errors with `acmart` class upon compiling.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's problem is different, but anyone trying to use `lmodern` and `newtxmath` together is likely to encounter the same symptoms, independent of the `acmart` class. In my case I was using `newtxmath` just for a few symbols, and the solution that worked best was to stop loading that package and instead copy out the definitions of symbols I needed from [newtxmath.sty](http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/newtx/tex/newtxmath.sty). For example (obviously this will vary depending on which symbols you need):

```
% from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452081/78411>
\makeatletter
\newif\iftx@libertine
\newif\iftx@minion
\newif\iftx@coch
\newif\iftx@ch
\newif\iftx@stxtwo
\makeatother

\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\uprho}{\mathord}{lettersA}{26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upvarphi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{39}

\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSm}{U}{ntxsym}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{AMSm}{bold}{U}{ntxsym}{b}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{ntxsym}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\Game}{\mathord}{AMSm}{97}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ggg}{\mathrel}{AMSm}{239}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\circledast}{\mathbin}{AMSm}{254}
```