# What is iftx@ch mean (in newtx)?

Tags: fonts, compiling

I have bought a new win10 pc, and struggling in installing my XeLaTeX stuffs. Compiler gave me error at untxmia.fd.

[image]

I guess it means that I miss-install some fonts/packages. But I can't figure out what does `iftx@ch` mean.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}


\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman Bold}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,nofontinfo,zswash,mtphrb]{mtpro2}



\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} 
\setCJKmainfont[ItalicFont={新細明體},BoldFont={新細明體}]{新細明體} 
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt


\newfontfamily\schola{Times New Roman}


\makeatletter
\newif\iftx@libertine
\newif\iftx@minion
\newif\iftx@coch
\makeatother

\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersffA}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersffA}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{+}{\mathbin}{lettersffA}{253}

\DeclareSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n} %OMS, txsy works
\SetSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bb}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\times}{\mathbin}{vvsymbols}{2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{vvsymbols}{0}



\begin{document}
$123$
\end{document}
```

The code of `untxmia.fd` is as follows

```
%Filename: untxmia.fd
%Created by: tex mia-drv
%Created using fontinst v1.933

%THIS FILE SHOULD BE PUT IN A TEX INPUTS DIRECTORY

\ProvidesFile{untxmia.fd}
   [2018/04/14 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxmia.]

\expandafter\ifx\csname ntxmath@scaled\endcsname\relax
  \let\ntxmath@scaled\@empty%
\fi

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmia}{\skewchar \font =127}

\iftx@libertine
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{
     <-> \ntxmath@scaled nxlmia
  }{}

  \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{
     <-> \ntxmath@scaled nxlbmia
  }{}
\else
  \iftx@minion
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{
      <-> \ntxmath@scaled zmnmia
    }{}

    \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{
      <-> \ntxmath@scaled zmnbmia
    }{}
  \else
    \iftx@coch
      \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{
        <-> \ntxmath@scaled zcochmia
      }{}
      \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{
        <-> \ntxmath@scaled zcochbmia
      }{}
    \else
        \iftx@ch
          \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{
            <-> \ntxmath@scaled zchmia
          }{}
          \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{
            <-> \ntxmath@scaled zchbmia
          }{}
        \else
          \iftx@stxtwo
            \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{
              <-> \ntxmath@scaled ntxstx2mia
            }{}
            \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{
              <-> \ntxmath@scaled ntxstx2bmia
            }{}

          \else
            \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{
              <-> \ntxmath@scaled ntxmia
            }{}
            \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{
              <-> \ntxmath@scaled ntxbmia
            }{}
          \fi
        \fi
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{sl}{<->ssub * ntxmia/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * ntxmia/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * ntxmia/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * ntxmia/b/sl}{}

\endinput
```

Comment: There may be some nonsense trash code in MWE, please ignore them.

Comment: I looked in newtx documentation and didn't found anything for usage with XeLaTeX... instead almost everywhere the code was using `fontenc` package... I suppose -but don't swear- this can not work in combination with XeLaTeX. So, please try changing your code to not use `newtxtext` or `newtxmath` and relevant content and tell us if it works for you. Sure are other (easier) ways to use fonts in XeLaTeX. See the related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281525/combination-of-newtx-and-fontspec-breaks-siunitx

Comment: @koleygr Thanks for replying. My old computer (win7) can compile the same code successively, so I suspect I might miss install some packages, or due to a big update of latest version of `newtx` package I can only install in today? (My old computer has an older version of `newtx`)

Comment: btw, is my MikTeX package [manager](https://imgur.com/a/Ye8kR2X) loss some package? I remember there are several "unicode-*" package in my old computer's package manager.

Comment: Sorry @Eric, I don't use MikTeX... If a package was missing you would get an appropriate to understand error (the command is not defined or similar)... I suppose the new version of your TeX distribution just can't compile and I think that the reason is the combination of `XeLaTeX` and `newtx`. I would try to avoid it anyway, because XeLaTeX is build in a way that makes simple the font handling and doesn't need an external (like `newtx` package's) help to do this.

Comment: `\iftx@ch` means "if charter should be used then ...". It is a switch from newtxmath. You could add `\newif\iftx@ch` as you added `\newif\iftx@minion` (and similar for the followings if's) but it is quite unclear if you get at the end the font you want. Instead of misusing the fd-files from newtxmath you should better write your own.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I primary use `mtpro2` except I like the + and - symbol from other times font (which is smaller). (I asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354431/extract-the-plus-symbol-from-newtxmath)) So I extract + and - from `newtx`. (I'm not familiar with LaTeX, so I am unable to write my own..)

Comment: On the other hand, can I remove all `iftx@...` between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`? Will it cause any problem?